# Can I run a script that uses 2 different command lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sage

Sorry if the title is vague, I am fairly new to Linux and I don't really know how else to put it. I am creating a script and when I run it, I got it to run Sage but after it does so, the next command isn't executed. I presume this is because the first couple were in the standard Terminal (bash?) and everything after `./sage` isn't -- here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6
./sage
#I also tried wait ${!} here but it didn't work
notebook("/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/projects/zero forcing.sagenb")
```

How might I enter the last command in Sage after it opens (assuming it's possible)? Thanks!

Edit: Here's a picture of my problem. Sage runs but I can't get it to execute the `notebook()` command after it opens.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `notebook()` as sage code using the `-c` option mentioned [[ **here** ]](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/options.html#command-line-options-for-sage). Try the below code.

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/sage # You can run the interactive shell directly
# At this point you have completely exited the sage interactive shell
# Presumably you want to run the below 'notebook()' after every interactive shell
# In that case do
/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/sage -c 'notebook("/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/projects/zero forcing.sagenb")'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know the terminology so I probably caused some confusion, notebook() is a function of Sage. I think it would be like me starting up Python with a script and then trying to execute a line of Python code -- I had to first start Sage in the script but the Sage command after that doesn't run.

Comment: Hmm, check out the edit at the bottom of my post. It's running Sage but the command just isn't being executed. Could this be because the command is trying to be executed before Sage is fully loaded? I noticed it took a second or two for that screen in the terminal to show up. This was my original thought with the `wait` command but I might have done it wrong.

Comment: What's happening in the current version of your script is you first have to finish the `sage` command; then the next thing will probably happen.  I think that this user just wants the notebook to start up automatically, in which case the command should just be `/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/sage -c 'notebook("/home/alex/Desktop/sage-7.6/projects/zero forcing.sagenb")'`.  However, see my answer for something probably easier.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to add the `-c ...` to the end of the sage like you said in your last edit. I didn't know that was possible!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is just to have one command that launches a notebook with a given name.

It turns out that in many Linux/Unix applications, there is automatic help at the command line.  Try

```
/home/alex/.../sage -n -h
```

to get some help on the notebook.  In particular,

```
sage -n -h --notebook=sagenb
```

gives a very, very long list of options, the first of which shows that

```
sage --notebook=sagenb directory=tp
```

will give you a new sage notebook server in the directory `tp.sagenb`.

All this said, I should also point out that the sagenb (sadly) is slowly becoming a legacy project in favor of the Jupyter notebook.  In Sage 8.0 a conversion from sagenb to Jupyter will become the default, and even now you can just do

```
sage --notebook=jupyter  --notebook-dir=/home/foo/bar
```

for that to start up.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think I was just confused about adding the arguments at the end of the `home/alex/...` because it's a directory and it threw me for a loop because I've only explicitly said something like `python arg1`. Also, I'm kind of glad, the Jupyter notebook seems much cleaner (let's hope it functions better too!).